# Python socket error: (OSError: [WinError 10057])

Tags: python, sockets, pyautogui, python-3.10

I'm making a python code that every 7 seconds send a screenshot through a socket, I have a server and a client. when I run the server I get an error:

[image]

the client takes a screenshot every 7 seconds with pyautogui and saves it with a name containing the date and time using the datetime module

client code:

```
import socket
import pyautogui
import os
import datetime
from time import sleep


client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("#hidden because of security reasons", 9999))


def send_img(img):
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_datetime = current_datetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    current_datetime = current_datetime.replace(":", ".")

    name = f"image_{current_datetime}.png"
    img.save(name)
    file = open(name, "rb")
    file_size = os.path.getsize(name)

    client.send(name.encode())
    client.send(f"{str(file_size)}".encode())

    data = file.read()
    client.sendall(data)
    client.send(b"<END>")

    file.close()

def screenshot():
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()
    send_img(img)

while True:
    screenshot()
    sleep(7)
```

server code:

```
import tqdm
import socket
import threading
import datetime

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip_addr = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
server.bind((ip_addr, 9999))
server.listen()


def send():
    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_datetime = current_datetime.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print(f"[{current_datetime}] New screenshot taken: {file_name}")

    file = open(file_name, "wb")
    file_bytes = b""
    done = False

    progress = tqdm.tqdm(unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1000, total=int(file_size))

    while not done:
        data = server.recv(1024)
        if file_bytes[-5:] == b"<END>":
            done = True
        else:
            file_bytes += data
        progress.update(1024)
    file.write(file_bytes)

    file.close()

print("[STARTING] SERVER STARTED...")
while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()

    file_name = client.recv(1024).decode()
    print(file_name)
    file_size = client.recv(1024).decode()
    print(file_size)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=send)
    thread.start()
```

if someone could fix this code it would be amazing, btw im using python 3.10 and pycharm IDE

I have tried to change the filename and other things but I keep getting the error.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: `data = server.recv(1024)` No, you should not be trying to `recv` on the server socket. In your setup you would call `send` and `recv` on `client` from `client, addr = server.accept()`.

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know that i shouldn't post images of errors, i will not do it next time. and I'm sorry but i don't understand your explanation of how to fix the code, can you maybe just make that part of the code for me, that would be incredible. I know I'm asking for much, but I'm a beginner and i really want this to work. :)

Comment: Similar code to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74821208/235698) and similar answer.  What bad example are you both starting with?

Comment: i created this code from a youtube video: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFVoMo6OMsQ&list=WL&index=10&t=643s)

Comment: That video is probably responsible for all the garbage python sockets code I've been seeing here for the last few months, all looking the same.